# xltable with mixed enumerate and itemize in columns

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate, xltabular

I want to obtain a table with an enumeration in the left column, and a list in the right column. Something similar to this (the items in the right column do not have to match the numbering on the left):

[image]

However, when trying it on LaTeX, I do not know how to properly merge all the rows of the right column and use it without errors the environment enumerate. I obtain the following with this code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{3D2B1F}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{66FF66}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{009900}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{myGreen}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}
\newlist{contenidos}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[contenidos]{label*=\arabic*.,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     nosep,
                     before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                     after=\end{minipage}}
\newenvironment{mytabenum}
               {\begin{tabenum}[label*=\thecurrentcontenidos.\arabic*.]}
               {\end{tabenum}}
\newenvironment{mycontenidos}
               [1][resume]
               {\begin{contenidos}[#1=contenidos] }
               {\setcounter{currentcontenidos}{\value{contenidosi}}\end{contenidos}}

 \newcounter{currentcontenidos}              


\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X  
       c@{}}
\caption{Saberes básicos y criterios de evaluación a conseguir en esta UD.}
\label{tab:Saberesbasicos}\\
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\thead{Saberes básicos (contenidos)} & \thead{Criterios de Evaluación}  \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endfirsthead
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\thead{Saberes básicos (contenidos)} & \thead{Criterios de Evaluación} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endhead
\begin{mycontenidos}[series] % use the optional argument "series"  for the first mycontenidos environment in the table only.
\item Necesidad de elegir un sistema de referencia para poder describir el movimiento de una partícula. 
\end{mycontenidos} & 


\\
\\
\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Variables cinemáticas en función del tiempo en los distintos movimientos que puede tener un objeto (posición, desplazamiento, velocidad, aceleración, etc), con o sin fuerzas externas. Obtener unas magnitudes a partir de otras usando el análisis matemático. Resolución de situaciones reales relacionadas con la física y el entorno cotidiano, aplicando el cálculo vectorial. 
\end{mycontenidos}&


\\
\\
\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Variables que influyen en un movimiento rectilíneo y circular: magnitudes y unidades empleadas. Deducción de las ecuaciones del movimiento. Movimientos cotidianos que presentan estos tipos de trayectoria.
\end{mycontenidos}&


\\
\\

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Relación de la trayectoria de un movimiento compuesto con las magnitudes que lo describen. Visualización gráfica de las funciones correspondientes.
\end{mycontenidos}&




\\
\\

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Comprensión de la diferencia entre sistemas de referencia inerciales y sistemas de referencia no inerciales para describir de forma cualitativa el movimiento relativo de los cuerpos en situaciones de la vida cotidiana y para resolver problemas sencillos en una sola dimensión en sistemas de referencia inerciales haciendo uso del principio de relatividad de Galileo 
\end{mycontenidos}&


\\
\bottomrule

\end{xltabular}
```

Comment: If the items on the left and the right are not supposed to match, why use a table in the first place (expect, maybe, for positioning everything in two columns)? If you still want to use a table, it only needs to have four cells: two for the column headers and the other two to hold the complete `itemize` (in the left column) and `enumerate` (in the right column) respectively.

Comment: @JasperHabicht because I want it for positioning everything without seeming that what is on the right corresponds to what is on the left univocally.